# How to log from handlers in tornado in console?

Tags: python, tornado

How to log from handlers in tornado in console?
I started app from console and put above handlers `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

and inside handlers

```
logging.info('RECEIVED HTTP GET REQUEST')
```

but nothing writes in console from handlers. I have tried with print but it doesn't work inside handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try by importing **tornado.options**

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/branch2.4/tornado/options.py

Line 465 - 468:

```
define("logging", default="info",
       help=("Set the Python log level. If 'none', tornado won't touch the "
             "logging configuration."),
       metavar="debug|info|warning|error|none")
```

This block of code register 'logging' as a command line argument within tornado command line argument parser and set default value to info.

In the development version they moved it to function 'define_logging_options' * in  'tornado.log' module.